# Spring boot app fails to run in STS but runs fine on command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

When I execute the project on the command line `mvn spring-boot:run -Dskiptests`, the project loads up just fine. But when I run the project from the STS IDE, Debug As --> Spring Boot App or Debug As --> Debug on Server, I get the below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map;
```

Comment: You don't mention what version of STS you are using. If its an older version then maybe you are hitting this bug: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4085 The bug messes with your runtime classpath and adds jars and/or source code that shouldn't be there (test scope). The extra elements added could cause library version conflicts that don't happen when you run from commandline.

Answer (score 2):

`NoSuchMethodError` usually points to a different version of a library being used than what is expected. As the app runs when using `mvn`, the version in your pom.xml seems to be fine. Please make sure if you have not added a different version of Guava in your project classpath. You may also make sure that you are using the correct version of your `Maven` settings.xml file in STS, and update the project with 'Force update of snapshots / releases' on.

**EDIT:**
I've just reread your qustion: `-Dskiptests` may cause the portion of your code that causes the problems be skipped. Please check your pom.xml if you have the correct version of Guava in it.

**EDIT 2:**
[The method you are trying to call](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap%28com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap%29) has been in Guava since 15.0.

Comment: Spring boot already provides a guava version to be used. If the OP is declaring guava, he should be omitting the version number and let the parent pom handle it.